# Retrieve Bounces from the emails are part from the journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views, email-tracking, bounce-management

I would like to retrieve the list of bounces of all the emails are included in the different journeys on a daily basis.

I know we would have to use the Data Views but I need help to build the query as it requires to join _Bounces, _Journey, _JourneyActivity (if I am not mistaken).

Could someone provide some light on how the query should look like? This is what I have so far:

Would it work like this?

```
select
j.JourneyName,
j.VersionNumber,
ja.ActivityName as 'EmailName',
s.EventDate as 'SendTime',
su.EmailAddress,
su.SubscriberKey as 'ContactKey',
s.SubscriberID as 'ContactID' ,
b.EventDate,
b.Domain,
b.BounceCategoryID,
b.BounceCategory,
b.BounceSubcategoryID,
b.BounceSubcategory,
b.BounceTypeID,
b.BounceType,
s.JobID,
s.ListID,
s.BatchID
from [_Sent] s
join [_JourneyActivity] ja 
on s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
join [_Journey] j
on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
join [_Subscribers] su
on s.SubscriberID = su.SubscriberID
join [_Bounce] b 
on s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = b.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might help (though you may have to tweak).... 1) Join _Bounce 2) Remove the Journey Name from the Query (to fetch all Journeys) ..... https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another really close to what [@VishalKumarCV](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/71982/vishal-kumar-c-v) suggested in the comments - [Query: Journey Builder Bounced Email Messages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_query_journey_builder_bounced_email_messages.htm&type=5).

A little bit updated query from the article:

```
select
j.JourneyName,
j.VersionNumber,
ja.ActivityName as 'EmailName',
s.EventDate as 'SendTime',
b.EventDate as 'BounceTime',
su.EmailAddress,
su.SubscriberKey,
s.JobID,
s.ListID,
s.BatchID
from [_Sent] s
join [_JourneyActivity] ja on s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
join [_Journey] j on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
join [_Bounce] b on s.JobID = b.JobID and s.ListID = b.ListID and s.BatchID = b.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID
join [_Subscribers] su on s.SubscriberID = su.SubscriberID
where ja.ActivityType in ('EMAIL','EMAILV2')
and s.EventDate < cast(cast(dateadd(hh,-72,getdate()) as date) as datetime)
and b.SubscriberID is not null
```

Notes:

- You can include your MasterDE to reference custom fields (would be similar to "ContactProfileData" DE in the linked use-case above)
- This query would capture all journeys
- If the account is part of an Enterprise 2 account - add `ENT.` prefix before `[_Subscribers] s`
- Because bounce data is not finalized for 72 hours after a send, searching for bounces in a send before 72 hours have passed is not recommended.
- Review other prepared SQL use-cases on the right-side menu [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5)